# Error while building Linux Kernel 2.6.10 Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'

Tags: linux-kernel

I am learning writing Linux Kernel Modules and following the book Linux Device Drivers. which instructs building and configure a kernel of 2.6.x . I am using kernel version 2.6.10. I followed the steps on [thegeekstuff.com/compile-linux-kernel](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheGeekStuff%20%28The%20Geek%20Stuff%29)
i.e. I after untarring in the /usr/src directory, I did

```
$ make menuconfig  #this opened up a gui
```

then I saved the config without making any changes, in the hope to enforce default configuration and then

```
$ make.
```

when I did make, it gave me this error and the warning’

include/asm/mpspec_def.h:78:2: warning: ‘packed’ attribute ignored for field
of type ‘unsigned char[6]’ [-Wattributes]

arch/i386/kernel/process.c: In function ‘show_regs’:

arch/i386/kernel/process.c:259:2: warning: pointer targets in passing argument 2 of ‘show_trace’ differ in signedness [-Wpointer-sign]
include/asm/processor.h:499:6: note: expected ‘long unsigned int *’ but argument is of type ‘long int *

arch/i386/kernel/process.c: Assembler messages:
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:384: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:385: Error: operand type mismatch for`mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:461: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'

include/linux/elfcore.h:92: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'
include/linux/elfcore.h:92: Error: operand type mismatch for`mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:583: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:584: Error: operand type mismatch for`mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:591: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:592: Error: operand type mismatch for`mov'
make[1](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=email&utm_campaign=Feed%3A%20TheGeekStuff%20%28The%20Geek%20Stuff%29):  [arch/i386/kernel/process.o] Error 1
make:  [arch/i386/kernel] Error 2

I have not written professional kernel code before so I am not sure if I should make any changes in the code. Can anybody help me with why this error occurred and how it can be removed. I used the default kernel config. prior to calling make using make menu-config.

The error in the process.c is in savesegment(fs,p->thread.fs); (all instances of the error are  from the same function)

Thanks

Comment: `I followed the steps on ...` - what **exact** your steps was? Did you create `.config` file by hand? Note, that kernel 2.6.10 is old, but the blog you refer to is relatively new (2013). Probably, it doesn't applicable for old kernels.

Comment: after untaring the linux tar ball, I installed ncurses and then

Comment: I installed ncurses followed by ---> make menuconfig. This opened up  configuration editor, I made no changes to the configuration, and saved it as it was. Next I executed make. and got the above errors. The linux tar ball was untarred in the /usr/src/ folder.

Comment: Linux 2.6 is *old*. I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't compile.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I used a kernel version who version was closer to my native kernel version ~ 3.11.1. and used make oldconfig instead. This was easier than figuring out each configuration setting for my architecture.

Answer (score -1):

It is not clear from your question that what are the exact steps you did.

This error may be due to some issues in configuration.

Please try the following steps and see if it solves the problem:

```
> make defconfig #Creates a default config based on your machine architecture
> make
```

Comment: after untaring the linux tar ball, I installed ncurses and then 
I installed ncurses followed by                                                                ---> make menuconfig.                                                                        This opened up configuration editor, I made no changes to the configuration, and saved it as it was. Next I executed make. and got the above errors. The linux tar ball was untarred in the /usr/src/ folder.

Comment: I tried  > make defconfig    followed by  > make but again make is giving the same errors. I had missed some initial warning last time, I have updated them in the main post now.

Comment: same problem with me as well.