# Compiling Linux kernel 2.6.10 from source - Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel

I am trying to learn linux kernel driver development. As per the book by Jonathan on LDD3, we need to try out sample examples on kernel 2.6.10. Now that i have dnloaded the source and trying compiling it, i am facing compilation issues.

```
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:384: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:385: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'
arch/i386/kernel/process.c:461: Error: operand type mismatch for `mov'
```

I discussed the same problem has already been posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37871813/error-while-building-linux-kernel-2-6-10-error-operand-type-mismatch-for-mov) , yet no solution has been given. I am blocked here. 
Can anyone pls help me out here, how can i progress further ? 
I tried searching for the solution, but in vain.

I am currently running kernel version 4.x, but i do not want to try examples on that as there will be many compilation issues if i try to modify and compile the examples against current version, nevertheless time consuming as well.

Comment: Please show the code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably this is a problem related to the compiler. You may try to find some workaround, yet still encounter more issues along the way. Maybe you should try to build this kernel on an older distribution, such as a distro running kernel 2.6.*.

Rami Rosen